# Make a cell editable in a ListView

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listview

I'm sitting in a VB-project and i have a ListView with 3 cells; a checkbox, a name and another text value. I want the last cell to be editable for the user. The second cell is also okay to have editable, no problems at all.

How can i set cells to be editable?

Right now i'm having this code to fill the ListBox:

```
Dim row(3) As String
Dim itm As ListViewItem
Dim txtbox As New TextBox

row(0) = ""
row(1) = "some value"
row(2) = "0"


itm = New ListViewItem(row)
itm.SubItems.Add("txtbox")

ListView1.Items.Add(itm
```

Any tips how to let the user change the last (or both second and last) cell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Winforms ListView control cannot be used like a DataGrid.
Only the first item can be made editable setting the property LabelEdit=True.

If you really want to be able to edit any 'cells' of the ListView when in Detail mode, you have two possibilities:

- Switch to a DataGrid
- Use one of the many extension available for free on the net (An example can be [found here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6646/In-place-editing-of-ListView-subitems))

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit a particular row in a listview but you can remove, and then re-add a value. Unfortunately I have no idea how to add multiple cells to the same row but know how to remove and add a single column cell in a listview control. Maybe this could be a start.

```
Dim item As ListViewItem = ListView1.SelectedItems(0)
Dim intIndex As Integer = item.Index

item.Remove()
ListView1.Items.Insert(intIndex, "New Text")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is trick with editing cells. You have to create offset textbox and put it to place of cell you want to edit (hit test, set location and size).

```html
Dim iRow, iCol as Integer

Private Sub TextOverlay_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        ListView1.Items(iRow).SubItems(iCol).Text = TextOverlay.Text
End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseClick
        Dim hit As ListViewHitTestInfo = ListView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
        Dim iWidth As Integer
        For iCol = 0 To hit.Item.SubItems.Count - 1
            If hit.Item.SubItems(iCol).Bounds.Left <= e.X Then
                If iCol = 0 And hit.Item.SubItems.Count > 1 Then
                    If e.X <= hit.Item.SubItems(1).Bounds.Left Then
                        iWidth = hit.Item.SubItems(1).Bounds.Left
                        Exit For
                    End If
                ElseIf e.X <= hit.Item.SubItems(iCol).Bounds.Right Then
                    iWidth = hit.Item.SubItems(iCol).Bounds.Width
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
        iRow = hit.Item.Index
        TextOverlay.Left = ListView1.Left + hit.SubItem.Bounds.Left + 3
        TextOverlay.Top = ListView1.Top + hit.SubItem.Bounds.Top
        TextOverlay.Width = iWidth
        TextOverlay.Height = 18
        TextOverlay.Text = hit.SubItem.Text
        TextOverlay.Visible = True
        TextOverlay.ReadOnly = False
End Sub
```

Comment: In most cases people suggesting this textbox-overlay solution forget about scrolling - the textbox remains on its place when the user is scrolling ListView. Another problem is that we need to implement a keyboard interface to provide the user with the ability to select any subitem to edit it. ListView has other serious drawbacks (read [this article](http://10tec.com/articles/editable-listview-replacement.aspx)), so I would definitely replace ListView with another control like a grid if you need to edit its cells.

Answer (score 0):

There is way to get currently selected item and then use BeginEdit() call on ListViewItem . 
To dispatch change: ListView.AfterLabelEdit Event